# Program in Js without engine?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since i've yet to see this question in these forums...

And having understood the syntax of Js and Jquery,

how would i actually go about continuing scripting in Js without 
having a 3rd party engine, or html parse it for me?...

I understand it's a tedious task, and if there's a specific 
answer or link, much appreciated.

I've seen so many applications written in Js and i assume not
every single one of them has been created in third-party libraries.

Basically: raw uncompiled script ran simultaneously.

Canvas, functions, variables, are any of these executable without
third party applications or html?.... thank's in future response.

NO REDIRECTS TO THIRD PARTY LIBRARIES OR APPLICATIONS PLEASE.

I mean cmon even the engines and libraries were written from somewhere...

Comment: what are you talking about? If you are trying to re-create some of the functionality of jQuery go take a look at Flanagan's "Javascript: the Definitive Guide". Look at the [DOM language binding|www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/ecma-script-binding.html]. You can do everything yourself. It just takes time. If you want to program in Javascript for system functions look at Node or the rhino project. Use Google

Comment: Javascript runs on a javascript engine, and only a javascript engine, as designed.

Comment: Windows has a jscript compiler, so technically you can't just run javascript from the command line, but you can compile it and run it.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kas1c51(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? If you want to code in javascript without third-party libraries, then do not include them in your code. That is entirely up to you. But you will need something to be able to run your code.